# table formatting help (centering on a dash)

Tags: tables, siunitx, booktabs

I'm not happy with the look of this table:

[image]

I think the dashes in the entries in the first column should align vertically. I don't like the extra space after the integer percentages in the second column, but don't want to make them all `.0`.

I'm open to aesthetic as well as technical fixes. Perhaps the heading on the second column should be `Marginal Tax Rate (\%)` .

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=2.1]}
\toprule
Bracket & {Marginal Tax Rate} \\ 
\midrule
\$0  -  \$9,075 & 10\% \\
\$9,075  -  \$36,900 & 15\% \\
\$36,900  -  \$89,350  & 25\% \\
\$89,350  -  \$186,350 & 28\% \\
\$186,350  -  \$405,100  & 33\% \\
\$405,100 - \$406,750 & 35\%  \\
\$406,750+ & 39.6\%  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the "dashes" in the first column should actually be dashes, `--`; they are now hyphens.  the requested alignment in the first column might be addressed by a nested `tabular`, aligned just after the last digit of the first value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r@{--}lS[table-format=2.1]}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Bracket (\$)} & {Marginal Tax Rate (\%)} \\ 
\midrule
0  &  9,075 & 10 \\
9,075  &  36,900 & 15 \\
36,900  &  89,350  & 25 \\
89,350  &  186,350 & 28 \\
186,350  &  405,100  & 33 \\
405,100 & 406,750 & 35  \\
\multicolumn{1}{r@{+}}{406,750} && 39.6  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Or possibly with some extra space around the `--` according to taste.

Comment: I would have gone for a \multicolumn{2}[c}{406,750+) myself.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I considered that but decided that logically that value is the start of a range with unspecified upper bound, so it belonged aligned with range starts even though it might look more balanced centred.

Comment: I went with centered on the last line, for looks. As start of a new range perhaps it should be `406,750 `-- <blank> .

Comment: @David Carlisle: I think the table would look nicer if the second column head were two-lined.

Comment: @Bernard probably both, so the units were both on the same row, but ....